# invalid argument type with const char* and char*

Tags: c++

I have a working example from another project that is *identical* to this, and it works. But for some reason in this project I cannot do it and I'm having one hell of a time debugging it.

I have a parent class with a constructor:

```
Shape (char* _name, char*_colour);
```

I then proceed to create another child class that uses Shape's constructor:

```
Square::Square(char* _colour, float _sideLength) : Shape("Square", _colour)
```

I get a error that const char* does not work, specifically with

`:Shape("Square",_colour)`

But I litterally have the **exact** same thing with a different project doing the exact same kind of casting and it works with no bugs. I'm currently blown away.

The *working* example ..

```
Car(char* whichType, int gasConsumption);
```

and a child class

```
Minivan::Minivan(char* whoMade, int mpg, int seating, int space, char* whatColor) : Car("Minivan",mpg)
```

which works fine. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: change all instances of `char*` to `chat const*` (or `std::string` if the source is not always a literal)

Comment: What's going on is that in C++, a "literal string" is a `const char *`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it was a literal string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation might be that one project uses C++ standard older than C++11, and the other uses C++11 or later standard.

Implicit conversion from string literal to `char*` is ill-formed since C++11, so the compiler is not required to accept such conversion. Prior to C++11 the implicit conversion was deprecated, but well-formed and thus compilers were required to accept the program.

The fix is to use `const char*` instead.

Comment: @RobertOchinski If changing `const char*` that points to a string literal to `char*` makes your program appear to behave differently, then your program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following -

```
char _name           = "YOUR_NAME";      // this is changed

const char* colour  = "YOUR_COLOUR";  // this is fine

Shape (char* _name, const char*_colour);
```